# Replace text by position?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt, reporting-services, xquery

I have the following XML file (It's actually SQL server reporting service RDL file). I want to replace the `<Value>` in the `TablixCell` to the `<DataField>` in the `Fields` by position. That is, "order date1" and "prod id1" should be replaced to "order_date" and "prod_id" respectively.

Preferably it can be done in SQL Server 2008 using XQuery. Xslt is fine to if not.

```
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="order_date">
      <DataField>order_date</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="prod_id">
      <DataField>prod_id</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    ....
  </Fields>
   ......
      <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                     ......
                              <Value>order date1</Value>
                     ......
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                     .....
                              <Value>prod id1</Value>
                     .....
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish?  My initial thought is that you can just find and replace in the rdl file...but the fact that you're trying to use XQuery makes me wonder if there's a bigger goal than replacing strings in this one file.

Comment: Yes, find and replace works fine if there are only several fields in one XML file. However, there are hundreds of columns in each of the 50  reports.

Comment: There is no "prod_date" in the provided excerpt of an XML file. The excerpt isn't a well-formed XML file and it even isn't a well-formed XML fragment. Please, edit and correct.

Comment: Does SQL Server 2008 support the XQUF (XQuery Update Facility) extension? If so, an answer using XQuery should be straightforward.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, Reporting Services Matrix format can pivot data to create arbitrary columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TablixCell">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Value">
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="//Fields/Field[$pos]/DataField"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run this with input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fields>
    <Field Name="order_date">
        <DataField>order_date</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="prod_id">
        <DataField>prod_id</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="xxx_id">
        <DataField>zzz_id</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.String16</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <TablixRows>
        <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.25in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                    <Value>order date1</Value>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                    <Value>prod id1</Value>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                    <Value>xxx id1</Value>
                </TablixCell>
            </TablixCells>
        </TablixRow>
    </TablixRows>
</Fields>
```

the result is the required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fields>
    <Field Name="order_date">
        <DataField>order_date</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="prod_id">
        <DataField>prod_id</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="xxx_id">
        <DataField>zzz_id</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.String16</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <TablixRows>
        <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.25in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                    <Value>order_date</Value>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                    <Value>prod_id</Value>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                    <Value>zzz_id</Value>
                </TablixCell>
            </TablixCells>
        </TablixRow>
    </TablixRows>
</Fields>
```